# Box shadow un-wanted curving

Tags: css

I want to add a box shadow to my Nav-bar/header at the top of my page.

When I do like this:

```
.shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #333 }
```

It works fine; however, because of the curvature you can see it curving at the bottom corners - I need it to be a straight down shadow.

Now because my header wraps the top of the page - the width is 100% - I could extend the side off-screen:

```
.shadow {
    ...
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #333;
    left: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    padding: 0px 10px /* compensates for the spaces created either side */
}
```

This way the curves are hidden off screen; however this seem's like a filthy, dirty solution - is this the only way to achieve the effect I'm going for?

I've thought of adding an after with a background gradient to simulate the shadow - like so:

```
.shadow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: gradientStuffICantRemember
    -o-background: -prefixedFallBackGradientBrackgroundForEveryBrowserEverCreated
    -ie-background: -prefixedFallBackGradientBrackgroundForEveryBrowserEverCreated
    -ff-background: -prefixedFallBackGradientBrackgroundForEveryBrowserEverCreated
    -webkit-background: -prefixedFallBackGradientBrackgroundForEveryBrowserEverCreated
}
```

However this is unbarabely filthy and disguisting.

Should I just extend out the header?

Comment: does the navbar itself have a rounded border?

Comment: No, css box-shadow's round off as the fade increases.

Comment: could you add a screenshot of the navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box-shadow` has another parameter called `spread` that defines the size of the shadow..... it could help:

```
box-shadow: h-dist v-dist blur spread colour;
```

Cheers!

Comment: excellent, I'd no idea it had that parameter, I can now simply extend the shadow instead of the whole element.